# Emulator freezing at startup

Tags: android, android-emulator

With the boot option set to "quick boot", when I try to launch an Android emulator, the emulator window pops up but the screen remains black with an information message at the top saying : "Cold boot : snapshot doesn't exist". A "dismiss" button is at the right of this text.

With the "cold boot" option, no message is displayed but the screen remains desesperatly black as well.

Even if I close the window, the qemu process remains alive. I have to kill it and remove the ".lock" files to be able to retry launching the emulator.

Additionnaly, my computer informs me that the graphics driver (AMD) was not responding anymore and had to be restarted.

Any idea about the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite a driver supposed to be up-to-date (that's what Windows used to tell me...), after installing the latest software from AMD (Crimson relive 17.7.1), the emulator now successfully works.

Answer (score 16):

I had an emulator frozen with application screen. No buttons worked. Screen didn't respond at all. This helped in my case:

**AVD Manager -> Arrow down in action section of preferred emulator -> Wipe Data**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to start it from command line using [`-no-snapshot`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common) argument. Similar to wiping the data out, just less work.
Doing that it will go into Cold Boot and it will work - similar to what @JohnnyFive suggested, but a bit less work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the emulator freezes every time startup if not cold boot.
I dig into it and finally find the reason.
I find that the SD card simulating function is relevant to this situation. If "No SDCard" is set, the emulator freezes at startup 100%!! So I revert the SD Card settings to the default then... voíla!
[SD Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp1M6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me recently. I need to do cold boot every time otherwise it freezes without exception.

I eventually solved(?) the issue by disabling auto-save snapshot for quickboot. Go to the emulator menu then set

```
Snapshots > Settings > Auto-save current state to Quickboot
```

to

```
false
```

After that, you need to restart the emulator.